# Equivalent definitions of infinitely divisible

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

My textbook states, that a probability measure $P$ is called infinitely divisible, iff

$$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\ \exists P_n \text{ probability measure: }P=\ast_{i=1}^n P_n$$

A random variable $X$ is called infinitely divisble, iff

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\ \exists X_1,\ldots , X_n \text{ iid random variables: } P^X=P^{X_1+\ldots +X_n}$$

Why are these definitions equivalent? I have problems with the implication

$$\text{$X$ infinitely divisible $\Leftarrow$ $P$ infinitely divisible}$$

I tried following:

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I can find random variables $X$ and $X_1$ such that $P=P^X$ and $P_n=P^{X_1}$, such that $$P^X=P=\ast_{k=1}^n P_n=\ast_{k=1}^n P^{X_1}$$
If I can show there **exist** $X_2,\ldots, X_n$, such that $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are iid, it follows

$$P^X=\ast_{k=1}^n P^{X_1}=\ast_{k=1}^n P^{X_k}=P^{X_1+\ldots+ X_n}$$

But how can I prove **existence** of $X_2,\ldots, X_n$, such that $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are iid?

Comment: Not an answer, but you are correct to notice that it is not trivial to magically find iid random variables. Kallenberg's Modern Probability has a chapter on this, I think the result is called Skorokhod coupling in it but don't quote me. But it is possible, though not just hand-waving.

Comment: Ok, so I am actually not really looking for a prove how to construct. I am just wondering if there is a theorem which just states that. So what you are saying is: "It is possible to find these variables", right? Because this would already satisfy my needs.

Comment: Maybe this post helps as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954711/given-a-random-variable-x-1-does-there-always-exsist-an-i-i-d-sequence-x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes that would suffice, Skorokhod coupling says something more specific, I'm sorry. But yes, it is possible, as the post shows.