# Clarification of Proof on Kac's Theorem for Characteristic Functions

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

There is a proof given here that I don't really understand, and was hoping someone more competent could explain it in some more detail:

[Moment generating functions/ Characteristic functions of $X,Y$ factor implies $X,Y$ independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287138/moment-generating-functions-characteristic-functions-of-x-y-factor-implies-x/287321#287321)

In particular, how come we are guaranteed $X^\sim$ and $Y^\sim$ such that $X^\sim \sim X$ and $Y^\sim \sim Y$ with $X^\sim$ and $Y^\sim$ independent?

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246445/36150

Answer (score 1):

For any set of distributions {D_1, ..., D_n}, we can always come up with a set of pairwise independent random variables {X_1, ..., X_n} s.th. X_i ~ D_i. This is why, without loss of generality, one can pick these two independent variables.